# Chrome and Firefox render a div in a table differently. Firefox shows a horizontal scrollbar. Is this a bug in one of the browsers?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

```css
div {
 overflow-y: auto;
 height: 100px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div>
    Hello World<br>
    Hello World<br>
    Hello World<br>
    Hello World<br>
    Hello World<br>
    Hello World<br>
    Hello World<br>
    Hello World<br>
    Hello World<br>
    Hello World<br>
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Running this snippet, FireFox displays a horizontal scrollbar while Chromium does not.

Is this a known but in one of the browsers? Why does this only happen inside a table?

Comment: This is due to the font-size. The same font size appears differently in these browsers.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov: No, it is independent of font size. You can change the font size to whatever you like and both browsers always keep behaving the same way.

Comment: I can see there is an of text overflow on both browsers (Chrome and Firefox) but the issue is with Chrome. Chrome automatically hides scrollbar in some cases.
Here's a discussion regarding this:

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/4565256?hl=en

Comment: looks like firefox applies overflow auto to the x axis too, where as chrome applies hidden instead

Comment: Firefox seems to be putting the scrollbar inside the width of the cell (as calculated by the text width) and so is overwriting the last few characters with the vertical bar and so sets the horizontal scroll. Chrome however puts the scroll bar outside the calculated text width so doesn't need a horizontal scroll bar. The default setting for a table is table-layout auto and the 2 browsers seem to interpret this differently.